# $mysql->info returns nothing

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','x','x','rock');

$q = $db->query("INSERT INTO names (name,surname) VALUES ('jack','daniel')");

var_dump($q); // boolean true

echo $db->info;
```

doing everything as described in manual but still returns nothing.

Comment: are you using a library for mysqli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `insert` statement is one of the below `info` function will return result

```
INSERT INTO...SELECT...     
INSERT INTO...VALUES (...),(...),(...)
```

And your insert is not satisfying this condition.

you have

`INSERT INTO names (name,surname) VALUES ('jack','daniel')`

if you change this to insert more than one record you will see the result from `info` function

if you change your insert query to insert multiple record in once you will get result

Try with below

`INSERT INTO names (name,surname) VALUES ('jack','daniel'),('jack2','daniel2')`